# Privileged subprocess starts in the wrong working directory

Tags: python, linux

Im trying to start a few python scripts from another, unprivileged one, using subprocess.Popen. Works good for the most part, but the ones that need root permissions dont work, i have narrowed the problem to pkexec, that is not staying at the working directory nor accepting it as parameter, thats because
This:

```
subprocess.Popen(['kdesudo','pwd'],cwd=sys.path[0])
#also works with sudo
```

effectively prints the cwd, whereas:

```
subprocess.Popen(['pkexec','pwd'],cwd=sys.path[0])
```

always stays at /root. (also tried passing env=os.environ to no avail)
i need to prompt the user with a gui, and the portability that pkexec offers over kdesudo/gksu. Any ideas?

**Edit:** Since its not possible to change pkexec's working directory, the following can be used to prompt the user for the root password across gtk and kde environments:

```
try:
    check_call('which gksu',shell=True)
    sudo = 'gksu'
except:
    print "gksu frontend not found, using kdesudo instead"
    sudo = 'kdesudo'
prompt = Popen([sudo, '<privileged command/script to run>'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to get `pkexec` to keep the old directory when invoking it's command because it [always changes to the target user's home directory](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/polkit/tree/src/programs/pkexec.c#n993).

It changes to `pw->pw_dir`, which is the home directory of the target user and there's no override for this.

I can't see a documented reason for this, but it could be simply a matter of attempting to ensure that the user executing the program can access their current working directory. It's been there since the creation of pkexec and I don't see any bugs relating to this behavior.

Comment: I see. given that theres no way around it, i have resorted to test for both sudo frontends instead. Editing my question for the sake of completeness

Answer (score 0):

I run pcmanfm file-manager as privileged user from current dir using `pkexec` like this :

```
pkexec  env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY  pcmanfm $PWD
```

User must belong to sudo group.

Comment: Oh. You are right.  I posted answer in wrong browser tab. Sorry about that.  Originally I have looked for "simple" replacement of gksudo which is not shipped  with Debian anymore and the answer reflects that topic.

Answer (score 0):

just use `--keep-cwd` in newest version of pkexec